# Hibernate Session return null even if table data exits

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve a student object from a student table but am getting `null`.

```
   public Student getStudentbyStudentName(String studentName) {
        final String query = "from Student s where s.studentName = '" + studentName + "'";
        return (Student)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).uniqueResult();
    }
```

I have also tried the following to retrieve the student object of studentName. It works until my web page refreshes. When page refreshes, the following returns null. Please help.

```
public Student getStudentbyStudentName(String studentName) {
    return (Student) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Student.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("studentName", studentName))
        .uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: SQL injection is still a thing?? Good luck with a student named `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` and similar. Please read up on how to execute / write queries using hibernate, read a decent tutorial and go from there. Your way will get you into trouble **fast**. http://bobby-tables.com/java

Comment: Added the code without query. The above code works until webpage refreshes. When page refreshes, the above returns null even if the record exists in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the name you pass in to that method is kind of Unicode, then you should place extra parameters in your MySQL connection url. E.g:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Second, but important. Your first code snippet is vulnerable for SQL Injection attack. Please use Criteria API (your 2nd snippet) or prepare your query:

```
from Student s where s.studentName = :name
```

in conjuntion with setParameter(...) method

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. I did try the 2nd snippet. The 2nd code works until my page refreshes. When page refreshes, the above returns null even if the record exists in the table.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at that method and confirm value of paramter studenName after refreshing?